# GA event goal tracking onSubmit not tracking in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I have a page with a order form. I want to track the onSubmit click in google analytics. This is the format I used. I have also added the correct information into google analytics in the admin/ goals panel.

```
<form method='post' id='form_catalogrequest' name='CatalogRequest' value='CatalogRequest' onSubmit ="return valid(this);_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'catalogRequest', 'Submit']);">
```

Is this correct way of setting this up? is there a better way to do this? because it is not tracking in GA when I process the form.

http://www.positivepromotions.com/catalogrequest.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that before your GA code you have `return valid(this);` Since you are returning something, all code after that is ignored.  You need to restructure your onSubmit code to allow the GA code to be triggered.  Looking at your `valid()` function from your link, it looks like it ultimately returns `true` if form fields are valid, `false` if not.

So there are two ways you can go about this:

**Method A:**  wrap the onSubmit code in a condition

```
<form method='post' id='form_catalogrequest' name='CatalogRequest' value='CatalogRequest' onSubmit ="if (valid(this)){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'catalogRequest', 'Submit']); return true;} else { return false; }">
```

**Method B:** move your GA code to within your `valid()` function:

```
function valid(form){

  // lots of form validation stuff that I didn't c/p to save space

  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'catalogRequest', 'Submit']);
  return true;
}
```

Personally I'd go for **Method B** as it is IMO cleaner.

Comment: Method A worked for me because I do not have access to the Validation. This was a awesome answer.